# Data analysis on multiuser environment

Tags: statistical-significance, data-mining, quality-control, history, functional-data-analysis

I have following environment that I'd like to analyze.

My company is divided in two teams:

- Insert Team (composed by 150 persons)
- Quality Check Team (composed by 10 persons)

Suppose that all people of first team compile a form with 10 text boxes, for example: name, surname, address, category, studies, preferences, hobbies, etc., and the second team (quality) analyzes a variable percentage of the data which are inserted.

Now I'd like to know which method could I apply to find good or poor members of first team, as analyzed by second team, **captured using historical feedback of all of the analysis made before**.

An example to understand better:

If the first team inserts 10 data points for the users, then we'll have 1500 data points to analyze. Suppose we define 10% of those data to pass to the second team. After their analysis and feedback, I'd like to use it to influence the next 10% of data capturing, for example, to focus attention on users that are less precise or on text box where there are more errors (which is the approach of major companies like Facebook or Twitter).

Comment: I don't think this question is necesarily about statistics--and even less about stat. sig., or history.  It seems to be about measurement and/or evaluation.  You're looking for a good method by which to measure performance on a task, right?.  Unfortunately you can hardly use statistics to determine what sort of responses are "precise"--that's going to require collaborative thought, hopefully leading to a systematic approach to evaluating the forms.

Comment: It's not a single task. It's multiple tasks on n forms. I have made this kind of example to make it easy. Do you think it's not a right place where post a question?

Comment: Can the Quality Check team make a definitive judgement on each text box's accuracy?  And will they be 'correct/incorrect' judgements or something with more distinction?

Comment: Yes quality check team make a definitive judgement and it'll be with around 5 or 10 distinction (correct, uncorrect, quite correct, quite uncorrect, medium...)

Comment: The weighting seems a bit weird; why not simply use all the data points at once to find an overall error rate per member of team 1? Of course, this error rate could be updated for every member of the first team when they add another 10 data points.

Comment: This answer's going to be lame because I don't have time to go into detail, but I think you should look up "active learning" and "inter-annotator agreement". Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume the quality control team just make a correct/incorrect judgement about each text box.  If so, this looks like a good candidate for a straightforward logistic regression model, with text box as one explanatory variable with ten levels, and team member as a second explanatory variable with 150 levels.  The response will be one if the entry is wrong, zero if it is right.

The estimates for the coefficient for each of the various explanatory variables can then be used to identify which team members and which text boxes have higher error rates.  This should then be fed into an algorithm for determining weighting for the future sampling.  Weighted sampling is a straightforward technique.  You will need some limits on the weighting - you don't want any text box to get below say 1/20 chance of being sampled, or any individual team member to get below 1/500 - so you choose an algorithm that sets those (or some other arbitrary levels) as the minimum for the weighting.

*Addition*

If the quality control team make a more nuanced judgement - say a rating on a four point scale from "poor" to "perfect" - then the procedure would be just the same as above but you could use [ordinal logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) instead.  The response variable would be this rating; the explanatory variables would still be the factors for team members and for text boxes.  You would still then need to use the estimated sizes of the effects for each level of the factor in an arbitrary algorithm that weights the chance of those text boxes and those users being included in the next sample.

Comment: If i'd like to have not a dichotomous judgement on each text box (like 1 or 0) but multiple, how could i change this method?

Comment: Instead of logistic regression, just use the appropriate form of regression for whatever the response is.  For example, ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: Could you explain me ordinal logistic regression model in my use case :-)

Comment: Hi Luigi - I've added a paragraph on this but really there's not much to say.

Comment: I don't understand the difference...

Comment: If you mean the difference between logistic regression and ordinal logistic regression, the difference is that in the former the response has to be a zero or one; and in ordinal logistic regression it can be an ordered factor (eg the five level ordered factor "very poor, poor, neutral, good, very good").

Comment: That to me raises concerns is that our output variable and y represents for us quality level that we want calculate. For both simple ordinal regression model to calculate the weights would have to say **a priori** who was y. In fact, regression models are created to verify the bond that exists between two variables in our case y (quality) x (number of errors) and calculation of beta (regression coefficient) for us represent that value which best allows me to connecting x to y.

Comment: In this case, y not observe directly but must obtain it and therefore should be given a value such as: poor good etc, before you actually know what is the same, ie to estimate the value of quality (but on what basis?). I think this is incorrect, since the quality is our unknown to be determined ...

Comment: Then what was meant by your comment earlier on the question 'Yes quality check team make a definitive judgement and it'll be with around 5 or 10 distinction (correct, uncorrect, quite correct, quite uncorrect, medium...) '.  This is the judgement I am suggesting should be the response variable.  If no such judgement is made then you have terribly confused everyone.

Comment: Maybe what i have found on this model it's not clear...Could you send me some links?

Answer (score 1):

Phase 1: **Rank the likelihood of errors for each input team member**

Use [poisson regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) where each person in the first team is a binary predictor variable and while the number of incorrect forms/fields is the response variable. However, you will need to have significant historical data in order to make this inference. Ordering the team members by the regression coefficients (descending) is going to give you the ranking.

Phase 2: **Use the ranking for sampling for quality team**

Once you have identified the regression coefficients (r<sub>1</sub>, ..., r<sub>m</sub>), you can create a probability vector (p<sub>1</sub>, ..., p<sub>m</sub>) := ((r<sub>1</sub>, ..., r<sub>m</sub>) + min(r<sub>1</sub>, ..., r<sub>m</sub>)) / (sum(r<sub>1</sub>, ..., r<sub>m</sub>) + m*min(r<sub>1</sub>, ..., r<sub>m</sub>)). Then, if you the quality team can handle #n validations, you should distribute them according to [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with MN(n, (p<sub>1</sub>, ..., p<sub>m</sub>)).